# Speed once One if is executed

Tags: php, performance

i would like to check if Web page Users use ie, any Other Browser or and iPhone. I have a php Script which Checks for every Browser, but that Means something like 20 elseif statements.

I think, that putting Firefox, Safari, chrome, ie and iPhone As the first statements would mean it only goes through all elseifs if the Browser is different to those above and otherwise stop executing. At least if i but a Break in there. Is that true or do i Need to Write a more simple Script for this purpose? thanks.

BTW sorry for all the caps, stupid iPhone autocorrection.

Comment: You should not be concern about 20 elseif statements. They will execute fast enough.
Also elseif statements are like switch-case-break, so no need to put breaks.
Which leads me to the thing that it's better to use switch-case-break than many elseifs, because is more cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an elseif chain if any of the conditions is true, the others won't be evaluated. You don't have to put in any breaks.

Also, even evaluating 20 ifs is so quick that you don't have to worry about it. Putting the most popular browsers first is a sensible idea though.

Comment: Thanks, awesome to get an answer that quick.
I am concerned about the about 20 statements though, because there are many ways webpages get slower and if you can have a reduce one reason without to much trouble, why wouldn't you.

Cases won't work for me though because I have to process some variables in each statement and cases do not look clearn anymore with that. 
Thanks agan.

Comment: Start optimization where you find the bottleneck.